# How to output top 100 Results in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

Am Really really new to all this hadoop stuff, all i have is the Wordcount.java 
file up and running. 
I was just wondering how would I go about outputting the top 100 
most frequent words from a file.

I have tried using Treemap but I just dont get it. 
Can someone give me a solution to this and explain it 
to me please and ty.

```
   public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
  private TreeMap<Integer, Text> words = new TreeMap<Integer, Text>();

  private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
  private Text word = new Text();

  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

String v[] = value.toString().split("\t");
Int count = Integer.parseInt(v[1]);

words.put(count, value);

if (words.size() > 100) {
     words.remove(words.firstKey());
        }

protected void cleanup(Context context)
                      throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        for ( Text wrd : words.values() ) {
            context.write(NullWritable.get(), wrd);
        }
    }

  }
}

 public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

  public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    TreeMap<Integer, Text> words = new TreeMap< Integer, Text>();

     for (Text value : values) {
            String v[] = value.toString().split("\t");
            Int count = Integer.parseInt(v[1]);

            words.put(count, value);

            if (words.size() > 100) {
￼￼￼￼        words.remove(words.firstKey());
            }
        }

    for (Text t : words.values()) {
            context.write(NullWritable.get(), t);
        }
     }
}
```

I dont even know if this code is done right but when i run it i just get all the words with the count beside them.

Comment: Can you post some code that you tried?

Comment: Added my current code to the question